# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are connected and why?

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb R$ are connected? 
$$\{x^2+x>4\}$$
$$\{x^2+x<4\}$$
$$\{|x|<|x-4|\}$$
$$\{|x|>|x-4|\}$$

Comment: Please add your own attempt, such that we can see your level and what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $u,v$ be the solutions of $x^2+x-4=0$ such that $u<v.$

Then $\{x \in \mathbb R:x^2+x<4\}=(u,v).$ Is $(u,v)$ connected ?

2. Show that $|x|<|x-4| \iff x<2.$ Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Try to understand how the sets looks like. For functions $f$ and $g$ the set
$$
\{x\in\mathbb R~:~f(x)<g(x)\}
$$
is the set of all points between the graphs of $f$ and $g$ where the graph of $f$ is below the graph of $g$. If you can draw $f$ and $g$, then you can make a sketch and see if the set is connected or not.

More straight forward:

Just compute the sets. For exampe x$^2+x>4$ is just a quadrativ inequality.